# constrained stars and bars problem

Tags: combinatorics

I want to know number of solutions for following equation, where $r_k$'s are non-negative integers, and there is a constraint on $r_k$'s such that $r_1 \geq r_2 \geq \cdots \geq r_K$

\begin{equation}
r_1+r_2+\cdots+r_K=N
\end{equation}

Comment: Wouldn't induction work? For $K=1$ there's only one solution, namely $r_1=N$. For $K=2$, we have $r_1=\lfloor 2/N\rfloor+1,\cdots, N$ and given $r_1=k$ then equation is just $r_2=N-k$. Apply the same idea to arbitrary $K$

Comment: Hold on.  Is $K$ fixed?

Comment: @SammyBlack yes it is

Answer (score 3):

We want the number of partitions of $N$ into **at most** $K$ parts.  For given the parts, there is exactly one way to arrange them in non-increasing order.

The number of partitions of $n$ into **exactly** $k$ (non-zero) parts is extensively discussed. As a start, please see the answer of Sammy Black. There is unfortunately no known nice closed form.

The number of partitions of $N$ into at most $K$ parts is *the same as* the number of partitions of $N+K$ into exactly $K$ parts.

For if we have a partition of $N+K$ into exactly $K$ parts, by subtracting $1$ from each part we get a partition of $N$ into at most $K$ parts. And if we have a partition of $N$ into at most $K$ parts, by adding $1$ to each part we obtain a partition of $N+K$ into $K$ parts.

Comment: Nicolas thank you that is good hint, but how can I find number the solutions for this case? I need the exact number of solutions for y work

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, there is no nice closed form formula for the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts. If you go to the Wikipedia article on partitions, and elsewhere, you will find useful *recurrences*. There are also useful asymptotic estimates. If your numbers $N$ and $K$ are smallish, the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts has probably been tabulated somewhere.

Comment: Can I find the number of partitions of n into exactly k parts using generating function in Sammy Black's answer? if yes I can do it myself and tabulate those numbers for my work

Comment: Yes. There are more efficient ways, but the generating function approach will do it. Then you can use my answer, $n=N+K$, $k=K$.

Comment: Sorry, I am insistently taking your time, you mean I use the generating function for k=1 till k=K and find the p(N+K) ?

Comment: That is another way to do it. My suggestion was to compute the number of partitions of $N+K$ into exactly $K$ parts directly.  But if you are drawing up a table for several $K$, the approach you mention lets us "recycle" some calculations.

Comment: You are welcome. For one generating function approach to partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts, you can start [with this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) The subject has been much studied, there are many recurrences. The asymptotics is also well-developed.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**  This response answers a slightly different question, where $K$ (the number of summands) is allowed to vary.  I will leave it here for posterity, but it doesn't deserve any upvotes.

---

These are the [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $N$.  There is no closed formula for $p(N)$, the number of such partitions, although there is a nice generating function:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{N=1}^\infty p(N) x^N &= \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-x^k} \\
&= (1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots)
(1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6 + \cdots)
(1 + x^3 + x^6 + x^9 + \cdots)
\cdots
\end{align}
$$
The beginning of this expansion is
$$
1 + x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 5x^4 + 7x^5 + 11x^6 + \cdots
$$
which is another way of saying that for $N = 0, 1, 2, 3, \dots$, the values of $p(N)$ are
$$
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, \dots
$$

Comment: what if $K \leq N$?